# Using aws smtp mail service in laravel 5.4 application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to send a mail to the company's office mail(other than email field for login) when a candidate appy for the job posting

**Controller function**

```
public function ImmediateApply(Request $request) {
    try {
        $request['resume'] = $this->image->uploadImage($request->resume, 'resumes');
        if (ImmediateApply::where('job_post_id', '=', $request->job_post_id)->where('email', '=', $request->email)->count() == 0) {
            $application = ImmediateApply::create($request->all());
            $job = JobPost::find($request->job_post_id);
            $company = Company::find($job->company_id);
            $company->notify(new JobApplication($job));
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'You have applied successfully',
                'code' => '201']);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            'code' => 400,
        ], 400);
    }
}
```

**company model**

```
public function routeNotificationForMail() {
    return $this->office_mail;
}
```

Now I'am getting the error

> 1.Failed to authenticate on smtp server with username "x" using 2
>   possible authenticators
>
> 2.CredentialsException in InstanceProfileProvider.php line 79: Error
>   retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server.
>   (Error creating resource: [message]
>   fopen(http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/):
>   failed to open stream: Connection timed out [file]
>   /var/www/html/jobs-website/laravel5.4/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php
>   [line] 312)

But when i check in smtp online test, I'am recieving the mail correctly

Comment: Check your user name and password

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't know the reason for the 1st error.It doesn't persist now.
Changing

```
MAIL_DRIVER = ses
```

from

```
MAIL_DRIVER = smtp
```

solved the 2nd error.
now everything working fine.

Comment: You will be Leave a comment instead of answer for this